# Xcode screen update error in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, simulator

Since I updated my Xcode to 9 (now I have 9.2) the simulator is acting weird. It's very slow and the main problem is that every time it has to update the screen (when something trigger, when some view moves, etc) it doesn't update to the last frame. For example: if I have a tableview and it updates the new results, they won't be showed until I make a new movement (like dragging the tableview), then the new results will be showed.

It happens with every device, and the same app runs perfectly in a real device.

I have Sierra 10.12.6 if it helps.

Comment: I don’t know if they will help, but have you tried the basic troubleshooting steps? (Cleaning, resetting simulators, rebooting your computer)

Comment: Yeah @JackDaw I've tried all of it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an Intel HD 3000 GPU (or similar) this can happen. It is a GPU driver bug and unfortunately I don't have a workaround for you at this time.

Using Simulator on a Metal-capable Mac (or switching to the discrete GPU if your machine has one) should work around it.

Comment: That's my graphic card yes. And also, my mac is not metal capable. This didn't happen before updating it, it seems strange to me that it can not be solved somehow.  You say it can happen with this graphic, is it a known bug?

Comment: Yes, this is a known issue currently. In Xcode 9.x the blitting of pixels was moved to the GPU (actual rendering inside the sim is still using software rendering).

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem too with a late 2011 13" MacBook Pro with Intel HD 3000 graphics. I had a look at the solution to a related issue described in https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88446‌ and thought I'd experiment with other values for FramebufferEmulationHint. A value of '2' seems to be working for me:

```
defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferEmulationHint 2
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work so far for my Macbook Air 2011: `defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferEmulationHint 1` - it didn't seem to work at first, but after awhile I seem to get good performance. It would never update to the "last frame" on transitions etc.